# If statement will not change text view when taking progress from seekBar

Tags: java, android, if-statement, textview, android-seekbar

I am trying to take the value of a seekBar and if that value is within a certain range to change the textView.

```
if (olivine.getProgress()==50) {
    rock.setText("Olivine rich");
};
```

This is what I have tried but it does not change the textView.

```
olivine.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
            int value = bar.getProgress();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar,
                                      int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean) {
            olivineper.setText("" + paramInt + "%");
        }
    });
```

The above puts the seekBar value into a textView. I have multiple seekBars in the activity if that makes a difference.

Comment: Show us more of your code

Comment: ==50 is not a certain range, try to use >=50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put your logic into the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`?

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean) {
    if (paramInt==50) {
        rock.setText("Olivine rich");
    };
}
```